# "Different reality" inside a black hole

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, reference-frames, event-horizon, observers

why does our perception of space and time entirely change inside a black hole? And why does time not stop inside it from the perspective of the inside observer, however, extremely slows down for the outside observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our perception of space and time would not change inside a black hole (if by that you mean inside the event horizon).

A person falling into a black hole would cross the event horizon smoothly and would not notice anything untoward at all unless the black hole was of low enough mass that the effective tidal forces across their body become large enough to notice. In particular - *proper time*, the time recorded on their own watch, continues to proceed in a forward direction at exactly the same experiential rate.

Perhaps what they would notice is that it would prove impossible for them to move towards a larger radial coordinate no matter what force was applied. They would also start to see strange optical effects/distortions associated with the extreme curvature of spacetime at small radii. There would then only be a finite amount of (proper) time before they were annihilated at the singularity, but the time interval between feeling uncomfortable and being annihilated would be less than 1 second (whatever the mass of the black hole).

I think what you are referring to is the oft-mentioned switch in the roles of the timelike/spacelike character of the $r$ and $t$ coordinates in the Schwarzschild coordinate system. All this means is that in order to ensure that proper time continues to increase then your $r$ coordinate must *decrease* when beneath the event horizon. In other words, the $r$ coordinate can only change in one direction and thus moving towards smaller $r$ becomes as inevitable as the passage of time in a forward direction in the exterior universe.